# Powershell calculating incorrect value for large bigint numbers

Tags: .net, powershell, bigint

```
[bigint][math]::pow(10,22)
```

Gives the correct result: 10000000000000000000000

```
[bigint][math]::pow(10,23)
```

Gives an incorrect result: 100000000000000008388608

```
[bigint]10e23
```

Gives a different but also incorrect result: 999999999999999983222784

I thought that System.Numerics.biginteger worked for arbitrarily large integers?

Is there something special that needs to be done to correctly calculate arbitrarily large numbers in Powershell, or a different method that must be used instead?

Comment: `[double]` can not represent `100000000000000000000000`. Two closest representable values are `100000000000000008388608` and `99999999999999991611392`. Thus, you need to not use `[double]` for intermediate result, but do all calculation in `[bigint]`: `[bigint]::Pow(10,23)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pow function takes double type arguments, and returns a double type result. Your int inputs are implicitly cast to double, and the double result is cast to bigint as best as able.

[Math.Pow Method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also see this response to [similar thing reported as bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5628). In that bug report, they suggest a function definition (including code) that will compute pow for big integer values.

Comment: [bigint]10e23 is also incorrect, is that a similar type casting error?

Comment: @Heltrix I strongly suspect that's the case, but I can't say with absolute certainty.